# How to simulate Flash's skew with pivot point?

Tags: algorithm, flash, image-processing

I have to simulate skew with pivot point created in Flash.
I've got the skew part ready, here's how I calculate the coordinates of point after skew:

```
function shearPoint(x, y, shearX, shearY)
    return round(x + shearX * y), math.round(y + shearY * x)
```

How do I add pivot point to this calculations?
I can provide pivot values using X,Y or using percentage.

EDIT:
added visual representation:
(top rects represent skewing with bottom right pivot point, bottom rects represent skewing with middle pivot point)
[image]

EDIT2:
Well, it seems that my original 'algorithm' is flawed, because for horizontal skewing it does not affect Y values of the point, which is incorrect.

Comment: substract pivot point , apply skew , add pivot point

Comment: Ummm no, I don't think this is the way to go ;) For example, delta X values of the point will depend on Y location.

Comment: Do you have a visual link to something similar to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: that equation is for skew starting from pivot point (so on this point is no skew), if your pivot is something else then specify closer ...